# How to change the height of MUI Datepicker input box in React

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

```
<DesktopDatePicker
    label="Expiration Date"
    inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
    value={self.didexpirationdate}
    onChange={(e)=>{
    setSelf({...self,didexpirationdate:e})
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}/>
```

How to set the height of this datepicker in react?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Date Component - V5**

TextField component is used as input box so you can directly add the size there. please refer https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#sizes

```
...
renderInput={(params) => <TextField size="small" {...params} />}/>
```

**Date Component - V6**

in V6 version `slotProps` is introduced to customise the appearance of date component. please refer https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-field/ for more details.

```
<DatePicker
  label="Small picker"
  slotProps={{ textField: { size: 'small' } }}
/>
```

Comment: I need to reduce the height of the datepicker

Comment: please someone for mui DatePicker not for mui TextField

Comment: this is work in datepicker on the textField

Comment: edited his answer... it's correct just put it in the compoent itself..

Comment: @Mr.P I rejected the submitted edit. to address the big repetitive code I already have added `...` three dots which means all above code is same as per question and only the required changes are added in the answer code.

Comment: no problem :) apparently, people don't get it. I am more people/customer-oriented.. but whatever ;-) just wanted to help more users ..

Comment: It has succesfully worked! I am thinking why the questioner did'nt provide green tick yet. Anyway thanks a lot brother

Comment: Is there a way to see the full example that @Mr.P gave?  I'm not getting any results putting this in my MuiDatePicker component.

Comment: @lowcrawler I have updated the answer for Mui Date component V6 version. in above V5 answer, all code is same as per question. only the last line of code is updated. which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In MUI 5 (x-date-pickers), you can use

```
<DesktopDatePicker
    ...
    inputProps={{ size: 'small' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

or just using styled of MUI:
const DatePickerCustom = styled(DatePicker)({
'& input': {
height: '100px',
},
});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For DatePicker of MUI v6, use slotProps - inputProps - style to set the height of its TextField.

```
<DesktopDatePicker
  slotProps={{
    inputProps: {
      style: {{
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingBottom: 0,
        height: '30px',
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```