# How to Change Date Picker height of material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using mui date picker and i want to customize it but css is not working on it i tried inline style as well as external styling by giving className but it dosent work
[I want to change its height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31mkb.png)

```
<DatePicker
            sx={{height:'35px'}} //its not working!!
            label="Due Date"
            className="DatePicker"
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
            value={selectedDate}
            onChange={(newValue) => setSelectedDate(newValue)}
/>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what didn't work exactly?

Comment: see the picture i attached. I am trying to change the height of DatePicker Componenet

Comment: I have seen the picture, yes. I can imagine how something that is a little bit higher would look like. I am saying you should post CSS with which you have tried to solve the problem and then we can help finding issues with it. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Show your work and then we'll give it a try.

Comment: How about this? [How to change datepicker height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613212/how-to-change-the-height-of-mui-datepicker-input-box-in-react). It is saying modify the input's height.

Answer (score 8):

I faced a similar situation using the new `@mui/x-date-pickers` to change the size from medium to small.

I had to use the `slotProps` of the `DatePicker` component as follows:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <DatePicker slotProps={{ textField: { size: 'small' } }} />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

[Check the doc.](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/)

Answer (score 4):

You have to apply the style by using the `sx` property in the `<TextField>` component and target the element with class `.MuiInputBase-input`.

Below is the code you need and here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuipickers-demo-mui-x-forked-1t0ibb?file=/demo.tsx) to play with.

```
<DateTimePicker
      label="Due Date"
      className="DatePicker"
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          sx={{
            "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
              height: "80px" // Set your height here.
            }
          }}
          {...params}
        />
      )}
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={(newValue) => setSelectedDate(newValue)}
    />
```

**Updated solution for later version 6.xx of DatePicker:****

```
<DateTimePicker
      label="Due Date"
      className="DatePicker"
      slotProps={{textField:{size:'small'}}}
       sx={{"& .MuiInputBase-input": {
          height: "80px"
        }}}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

Comment: Did not work for me with the latest.6.18

Comment: Thanks @sureshvv for pointing it out. I have updated my answer just in case someone finds it helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use an other type of date picker instead. for example `StaticDatePicker` for large height data picker

```
<StaticDatePicker
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
  setSelectedDate(newValue);
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        <DatePicker slotProps={{textField:{size:'small'}}}
           sx={{"& .MuiInputBase-input": {
              width: "120px"
            }}} />
```

@Akis's answer did not work with version 6.18